# Is there a method to print the duration of the script and save it inside the csv?

Tags: python, performance, time, python-requests, timeit

I would like to print the duration of the script and save it inside the csv. What would be the best method?

```
import requests

with open('infile.txt', 'r') as f:
    urls = f.readlines()

datalist=[]
for url in urls:
    data = requests.get(url)
    datalist.append(data.text)

with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in datalist:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Comment: you can do it via bash or python. Which one do you prefer?

Comment: @bigbounty I prefer python please. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `datetime` module.

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime

def run():
    with open('infile.txt', 'r') as f:
        urls = f.readlines()

    datalist=[]
    for url in urls:
        data = requests.get(url)
        datalist.append(data.text)

    with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as f:
        for item in datalist:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)

startTime = datetime.now()
run()
print(datetime.now() - startTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way you could do this is by using the built-in time module. Get the time before the execution, get the time after the execution, subtract them and you get the time taken for your script to run. You could then just export it to your csv just like every other text.

```
import time
# STEP 1: Get start time
start_time = time.time()
# Step 2: Run your code you want to time
result = func_one(some_param)
# Step 3: Calculate total time elapsed
end_time = time.time() - start_time
```

Comment: How would I place the code in step two? Would I place the entire code inside the step or after?